# Iframe breaking script

Tags: iframe

How can create an iframe breaking script which shows a alert box if the page is loaded in an iframe and when the alert box is clicked, it should break the frame and the script should be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (top != window) {
  alert("please don't load my in a frame, thx.");
  top.location.href = location.href;
}
```

might do the trick.

Comment: Thank you so much. BTW, could it be possible that the parent window somehow manages to stop this from happening in the the iframe.